# Kylin - Error message on sudo apt update - E: The repository 'file:/media/kylin/Kylin-4.0.2 juniper Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: repository, kylin

I installed this Linux distro that I found on ubuntukylin.com called YHKylin OS, it's based off of Ubuntu 16.04. But when I do sudo apt update, I get an error.

`E: The repository 'file:/media/kylin/Kylin-4.0.2 juniper Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

I tried asking this on Yahoo Answers, but it got taken down for some reason. If this gets taken down, I would like to know why.

Comment: I have open a bug in launchpad for a similar question:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntukylin/+bug/1767793

Comment: **Ubuntu Kylin is an official Ubuntu Flavour** http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntukylin/releases/16.04/release/ so get the official release from there.